# Google BigQuery: Error: Invalid schema update. Field has changed mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to append the results of a query to another table.

It doesn't work and sends out the following error:

**Error: Invalid schema update. Field X has changed mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE.**

The field X is indeed REQUIRED, but I don't try to insert any NULL-values into that specific column (the whole table doesn't have a single NULL value).

This looks like a bug to me. Anyone knows a way to work around this issue?

Comment: Please share the query (and any other parameters used to configure the request to BigQuery). Legacy SQL or standard SQL?

Comment: I switched from Legacy SQL to Standard SQL and the issue was gone. Something to keep in mind next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed after switching from Legacy SQL to Standard SQL.